# JaxB unmarshal XML with Capital letter Tags

Tags: xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I use Sprint 3.0.5 and the included jaxb marshaller to communicate with a REST service. The service provided by a different company sends via POST an XML to my Service and i have to unmarshal that XML in my Java objects and process them.

The problem i have is, that the XML tags start with a capital letter (they wont change that) and therefore the JAXB marshaller cant unmarshal the object.

The XML looks like the following:

```
<Ssm_Packet>
<Version>1</Version>
<Protocol_ID>0</Protocol_ID>
<Packet_Id>{84ca597c-05e2-4357-897c-892f428c35ce}</Packet_Id>
<Priority>0</Priority>
<Source_Address>1:11111111111111</Source_Address>
<Destination_Address>2:LA3222222222222</Destination_Address>
<Body>Some TExt</Body>
<Billing />
</Ssm_Packet>
```

The bean I defined for jaxb looks like the following:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;


@XmlRootElement(name="Ssm_Packet")
public class Ssm_Packet {
@XmlElement(name="Version")
private String version;
private String protocol_ID;
private String packet_Id;
private String priority;
private String source_Address;
private String destination_Address;
private String body;
private String billing;
/**
 * @return the version
 */
public String getVers() {
    return version;
}
/**
 * @param version the version to set
 */
public void setVers(String Version) {
    this.version = Version;
}
/**
 * @return the protocol_ID
 */
public String getProtocol_ID() {
    return protocol_ID;
}
/**
 * @param protocol_ID the protocol_ID to set
 */
public void setProtocol_ID(String Protocol_ID) {
    this.protocol_ID = Protocol_ID;
}
/**
 * @return the packet_Id
 */
public String getPacket_Id() {
    return packet_Id;
}
/**
 * @param packet_Id the packet_Id to set
 */
public void setPacket_Id(String Packet_Id) {
    this.packet_Id = Packet_Id;
}
/**
 * @return the priority
 */
public String getPriority() {
    return priority;
}
/**
 * @param priority the priority to set
 */
public void setPriority(String Priority) {
    this.priority = Priority;
}
/**
 * @return the source_Address
 */
public String getSource_Address() {
    return source_Address;
}
/**
 * @param source_Address the source_Address to set
 */
public void setSource_Address(String Source_Address) {
    this.source_Address = Source_Address;
}
/**
 * @return the destination_Address
 */
public String getDestination_Address() {
    return destination_Address;
}
/**
 * @param destination_Address the destination_Address to set
 */
public void setDestination_Address(String Destination_Address) {
    this.destination_Address = Destination_Address;
}
/**
 * @return the body
 */
public String getBody() {
    return body;
}
/**
 * @param body the body to set
 */
public void setBody(String Body) {
    this.body = Body;
}
/**
 * @return the billing
 */
public String getBilling() {
    return billing;
}
/**
 * @param billing the billing to set
 */
public void setBilling(String Billing) {
    this.billing = Billing;
}
}
```

Now if i let JAXb unmarshal the XML in that object, he wont fill in the values of the xml unless the xml tags are without a capital letter.

Can anyone help me how to unmarshal that values into my bean?

thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `@XmlElement` annotation to specify the element name that corresponds to each of your fields/properties.

```
/**
 * @return the protocol_ID
 */
@XmlElement(name="Protocol_ID")
public String getProtocol_ID() {
    return protocol_ID;
}
```

If you want to annotate your fields instead, then you will need to set `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)`:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Ssm_Packet")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Ssm_Packet {
    @XmlElement(name="Version")
    private String version;
}
```

[**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) also contains an extension where you can override the standard JAXB algorithm for converting Java field/property names to XML names:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/overriding-jaxbs-name-mangling.html

Comment: Thx alot, that fixed my Problem. Will check out now the links you provided.